# Roku: How to read text entered from keyboard in BrightScript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am writing an application for Roku in which I need to enter some text using keyboard and get the text in main.brs

I started with KeyboardExample given here: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Widgets+Markup (Keyboard Markup).

To pass the text to main.brs, I used global node of the roSGScreen as given in the below link.
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Scene+Graph+Data+Scoping (Global Scope).

The following code is present in my main.brs

```
Sub getTextFromUser()
    screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
    m.textPort = CreateObject("roMessagePort") 
    screen.setMessagePort(m.textPort)
    m.global = screen.getGlobalNode()
    m.global.id = "GlobalNode"
    m.global.addFields( {myText: "Not initialized"} )
    scene = screen.CreateScene("KeyboardExample")
    screen.show()
    while(true)
        msg = wait(0, m.textPort)
        msgType = type(msg)

       if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
           if msg.isScreenClosed()
               myURL = m.global.myText
               return
           end if
       end if
  end while
End Sub
```

I have added the following code in keyboard.xml

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean 
    keyboard = m.top.findNode("exampleKeyboard")  

    if keyboard.text <> invalid 
        m.global.myText= keyboard.text
    end if

    return false 
end function
```

I am copying *m.global.myText* to a local variable when I receive *roSGScreenEvent.isScreenClosed* event.

The issue is when *roSGScreenEvent.isScreenClosed* is receved *m.global.myText* becomes invalid.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I read about the *roSGNode.ObserveField* in the following link.
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Handling+Node+Field+Changes

I added an observer for "*text*" field of the Keyboard as below.

```
keyboard.ObserveField("text", "changetext")
```

and I was getting changetext() callback whenever a key was pressed. But this method had the same issue.

According to the above link, an *roMessagePort* object can be passed to observer instread of function pointer. So I passed *textPort* to *keyboard.xml* using *global* variable and passed it to observer as below.

```
keyboard.ObserveField("text", m.global.myTextPort)
```

My expectation was to get *roSGNodeEvent* at *textPort* whenever a key was pressed. But I am not getting any events.

Answer (score 1):

Global node is shared between nodes of one Rosgscreen, if you screen becomes closed, you can't access it's fields. So you have to observe keyboards text and update you local variable myurl each time text is entered.

Comment: Thank you @Roman Parashchyn! Here my observation is that the main thread will be waiting at "msg = wait(0, m.textPort)". For now I changed the timeout value to 100ms and copying text to my local variable. Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: M.global.observefield("fieldname", port) will generate event each time this field changes. You will receive rosgnodeevent   where you can read proper value

Comment: Hi @Roman Parashchyn, I added M.global.observefield("text", m.textPort) in main.brs but it did not work. But "text" is a field in keyboard component right? Is it fine if I just put "text" in observefield()?

Comment: Did you check if m.global.mytext was really created and has any value? Also from your description you used m.global.mytextport, ports could not be stored in rosgnodes, check if it's valid.

Comment: Also, try to print all none invalid messages from port

Comment: (1) Now I am not using m.global.mytextport. I have put M.global.observefield("text", m.textPort)  inside Sub getTextFromUser().  (2) I gave 100ms timeout in wait() and printed all the messages. I am getting invalid message prints. So port should be valid.

Comment: Could you please send your while loop

Comment: while(true)
    msg = wait(0, m.textPort)
    msgType = type(msg)
    
    print "Got message: ";msg
    
    if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
      if msg.isScreenClosed()
 
         return
      end if
    end if end while

Comment: Try to move all the stuff with creating and observing global node after show() is called

Comment: OK.. Can you answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300097/roku-reading-a-text-file-present-in-server This will also help..